# Jetpack Compose text is not getting updated

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I am trying a Tic tac toe sample project. Once user performs click I am receiving callbacks but when trying to update text it's not basically updating text. Below is my code, please help. So far I have tried Need to put below text to shut-up SO error bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla:

```
enum class Player {
    Human, Computer
}

var board = arrayListOf("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")
private var currentPlayer = Player.Computer

fun updatePosition(position: Int) {
    if (board[position].isEmpty())
        if (currentPlayer == Player.Human) {
            board[position] = "X"
            currentPlayer = Player.Computer
        } else {
            board[position] = "O"
            currentPlayer = Player.Human
        }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        ComposeTicTacToeTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                Greeting(board, this::updatePosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(board: ArrayList<String>, onclick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Column{
        Row {
            Cell(board[0]) { onclick(0) }
            Cell(board[1]) { onclick(1) }
            Cell(board[2]) { onclick(2) }
        }
        Row {
            Cell(board[3]) { onclick(3) }
            Cell(board[4]) { onclick(4) }
            Cell(board[5]) { onclick(5) }
        }
        Row {
            Cell(board[6]) { onclick(6) }
            Cell(board[7]) { onclick(7) }
            Cell(board[8]) { onclick(8) }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Cell(
    name: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(130.dp)
            .height(130.dp)
            .padding(12.dp),
        elevation = 8.dp,
        contentColor = Color.Black,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(80.dp),
        onClick = onClick
    ) {
        Text(
            name, fontSize = 80.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(color = Color.Yellow)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to let Compose know that recomposition is needed, you have to use a special `State` wrapper for your values. In case of array, you can use `mutableStateListOf` instead of `arrayListOf`:

```
val board = mutableStateListOf("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")
```

For more details I suggest you start with state in Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.